# Need to write a procedure to fetch given rownums

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need to write one procedure to pick the record for given rows

for example

```
procedure test1
(
start_ind number,
end_ind number,
p_out ref cursor
)

begin
opecn p_out for
select * from test where rownum between start_ind and end_ind;
end;
```

when we pass start_ind 1 and end_ind 10 its working.But when we change start_ind to 5

then query looks like

```
select * from test where rownum between 5 and 10;
```

and its fails and not shows the output.

Please assist how to fix this issue.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The rownum is assigned and then the where condition evaluated. Since you'll never have a rownum 1-4 in your result set, you never get to rownum 5.  You need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT rownum AS rn, t.* 
      FROM (
        SELECT t.*
          FROM test t
         ORDER BY t.whatever
      )
     WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
)
WHERE rn >= 5
```

You'll also want an order by clause in the inner select, or which rows you get will be undefined.

This article by Tom Kyte pretty much tells you everything you need to know: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html

Comment: Actually, the `ORDER BY` should not be in the inner query, but in an inner query of the inner query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  from (SELECT rownum AS rn, t.*
          FROM MyTable t
         WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
        ORDER BY t.NOT-Whatever 
       -- (its highly important to use primary or unique key of MyTable)        
 WHERE rn > 5
```

***As a hint***, :
Typically we use `store-procedures` for data validation, access control, extensive or complex processing that requires execution of several SQL statements. Stored procedures may return result sets, i.e. the results of a SELECT statement. Such result sets can be processed using cursors, by other stored procedures, by associating a result set locator, or by applications

I think you are going to use the ruw-number to fetch paged queries.
Try to create a `generic select query` based on the idea mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1) Your table is an index-organized table. So its data is sorted. You would select those first rows you want to avoid and based on that get the next rows you are looking for:

```
create or replace procedure get_records
(
  vi_start_ind     integer,
  vi_end_ind       integer,
  vo_cursor    out sys_refcursor
) as
begin
  open vo_cursor for
    select * 
    from test
    where rownum <= vi_end_ind - vi_start_ind + 1 
    and rowid not in
    (
      select rowid 
      from test
      where rownum < vi_start_ind
    )
  ;
end;
```

2) Your table is not index-organized, which is normally the case. Then its records are not sorted. To get records m to n, you would have to tell the system what order you have in mind:

```
create or replace procedure get_records
(
  vi_start_ind     number,
  vi_end_ind       number,
  vo_cursor    out sys_refcursor
) as
begin
  open vo_cursor for
    select * 
    from test
    where rownum <= vi_end_ind - vi_start_ind + 1 
    and rowid not in
    (
      select rowid from
      (
        select rowid 
        from test
        order by somthing
      )
      where rownum < vi_start_ind
    )
    order by something
  ;
end;
```

All this said, think it over what you want to achieve. If you want to use this procedure to read your table block for block, keep in mind that it will read the same data again and again. To know what rows 1,000,001 to 1,000,100 are, the dbms must read through one million rows first.